# Group_by with a twist. Calculate mean or certain rows values with zeros for the rest of the rows

Tags: r, ggplot2, group-by, dplyr

I have a dataset of fish species sampling:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T9ld6XyaSJ8OL5EcQwpbVLxFbhKBN4Zx/view?usp=sharing .

I'm hope to calculate the average `CPUE` of each species (`newscientific`) by year. I have code that calculates the average `CPUE` across multiple references for each year:

```
BD %>% 
  group_by(newscientific, year) %>% 
  summarise(mean_CPUE_year = mean(CPUE))
```

However, I also need to include the implicit `0` measurement when a species is not observed in a `Reference`.

Additionally, I would like to limit my analysis to the 6 species with the highest mean `CPUE`. The following code is close but does not factor in the implicit `0` measurements when a species is not observed in a `Reference`:

```
most_common <- BD %>%
  group_by(newscientific) %>% 
  summarise(mean_cpue = mean(CPUE)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(desc(mean_cpue)) %>% 
  top_n(6) %>%        #Can change the top species by modifying this number
  pull(newscientific)
```

Ultimately, I would like to plot the mean `CPUE` trend over time for each of the 6 species.

Here is the code I have tried so far, but it does not factor in the 0's for `Reference` rows where that species was not caught.

```
BD %>% 
  group_by(newscientific, year) %>% 
  summarise(mean_CPUE_year = mean(CPUE)) %>% 
  filter(newscientific %in% most_common) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=year, y= mean_CPUE_year)) + 
  geom_line(aes()) +
  labs(title = "Annual Mean CPUE of Top 6 Species", y = "Mean CPUE (# fish/100m2)", x = "Date")+
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(2007.9, 2018.1), breaks=seq(2008, 2018, 1)) + 
  theme_bw() + theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                     panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
                     axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(newscientific), nrow = 3, ncol = 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach with `complete` from `tidyr`:

Before we call `complete`, we need to `group_by = year`, so that this column is filled correctly. Then we can complete each `Reference` for all combinations of `newscientific`. We can use the `fill` argument to fill in `0` instead of `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
BD %>%
  dplyr::select(year, CPUE, newscientific, Reference) %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  complete(Reference, newscientific, fill = list(CPUE = 0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(newscientific) %>% 
  mutate(mean_cpue = mean(CPUE)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  dplyr::filter(mean_cpue %in% sort(unique(mean_cpue),decreasing = TRUE)[1:6]) %>%
  group_by(newscientific, year) %>% 
  summarise(mean_CPUE_year = mean(CPUE)) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=year, y= mean_CPUE_year)) + 
  geom_line(aes()) +
  labs(title = "Annual Mean CPUE of Top 6 Species", y = "Mean CPUE (# fish/100m2)", x = "Date")+
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(2007.9, 2018.1), breaks=seq(2008, 2018, 1)) + 
  theme_bw() + theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                     panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
                     axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(newscientific), nrow = 3, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

**Data**

```
BD <- readr::read_csv("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=1T9ld6XyaSJ8OL5EcQwpbVLxFbhKBN4Zx&export=download")
```

Comment: This is very close and I thank you for help. However Lucania parva was only caught in 10 or 12 steps. It was originally identified by myself as a in the top 6 because that selection method was not factoring in he implicit 0 measurements when lucania parva was not caught in those reference numbers. In a sense it was artificially (or relatively) inflated due to high catches in those few References that is was caught. Thanks

Comment: That should take care of your problem.

Comment: Works perfect, Thank you!